# Gamma spectrum: Question about cross sections

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radiation

If I have a gamma spectrum and I suspect that I should have an isotope, Fe-59 for example, present in the environment, I will then look here:

http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=260059

to see what spectral lines I might expect. As we can see in this case, there are high emission intensities at 1099KeV and 1291KeV. If I do not observe lines at these energies (or any of the others), can I then outright conclude that the isotope is not present?

It's worth clarifying that the reason I would expect this specific isotope to be present is because it's part of the decay chain of Cr-59, which I also expect to be present.

Comment: It depends on the sensitivity of your instrument. It's probably more accurate to state that if your instrument doesn't pick up any of these Fe-59 gammas, that Fe-59 presence is below the detection limit of your instrument. Your expectation that Fe-59 might be present because Cr-59 is present is also relative. It will depend on Cr-59 levels and rate of decay into Fe-59 whether or not Fe-59 gammas will be present in detectable amounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The peaks at $E = 1099\:\mathrm{keV}$ ($P = 56.5\:\%$) and $E = 1292\:\mathrm{keV}$ ($P = 43.2\:\%$) are the most important gamma lines for Fe-59. If a significant Fe-59 activity is present in your sample and your detector is sufficiently sensitive in this energy range, you should be able to see both peaks. The intensity of both peaks might be reduced due to coincidence summing (so-called “summing out”), but the peaks would not completely disappear.

However, if you do not see the peaks in the spectrum, you cannot simply say that the isotope is not present.

First you should calculate the *decision threshold*. If the result of your measurement exceeds the decision threshold, you may conclude that the nuclide is present. Otherwise, the nuclide is assumed to be absent. Then you should calculate the corresponding *detection limit*, which is the smallest true activity that is detectable by your measuring method.

Thus, if the measured peak intensity is below the decision threshold, you can only guarantee that the activity in the sample is below the detection limit, but you cannot guarantee that the activity is zero.

Comment: Loong, could you explain how to calculate the _decision threshold_? Thank you.

Comment: @Gert The explanation would be too long for this format. The standard method for the determination of the decision threshold and the detection limit is described in [ISO 11929](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=43810).

Comment: Many thanks for your informative answer. I hadn't heard of coincidence summing before, is there a way in which you could give a quick explanation of it - when and how it arises? Many thanks.

Comment: @MattS If one gamma ray of 1099 keV and one gamma ray of 1292 keV are detected approximately at the same time, the spectrum will show only one count at 2391 keV (= 1099 keV + 1292 keV) due to “coincidence summing” but no counts at 1099 keV and 1292 keV. Therefore, the apparent efficiency for the peaks at 1099 keV and 1292 keV is reduced due to “summing out”. – You can see this effect if you put a strong Co-60 calibration source close to the detector (1333 keV + 1173 keV).

Comment: @Gert If you are still interested, you can find two examples for the calculation of the decision threshold and the detection limit in [this sandbox post on meta.chemistry.se](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3283/7951). You can also see why the complete explanation for gamma spectroscopy would be too long for this format.